# A particular limit: $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \log_t (t^x+t^y)$

Tags: calculus

Which is $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \log_t (t^x+t^y)$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$ and $t>1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\;x< y\;$ :

$$\log_t\left(t^x+t^y\right)=\log_t\left(t^y\left(1+t^{x-y}\right)\right)=y+\log_t\left(1+t^{x-y}\right)$$

But

$$x<y< 0\implies t^{x-y}\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{}0\implies \log_t\left(1+t^{x-y}\right)=\frac{\log(1+t^{x-t})}{\log t}\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{}=0$$

Of course, if $\;x=y\;$ then we **also**  have

$$\log_t(2t^x)=\log_t2+x=\frac{\log 2}{\log t}+x\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{}x=y$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let us assume $x<y$. So, $$2t^x\leq t^x+t^y\leq 2t^y$$ Now, apply logarithms.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Perhaps you want $\;t^y\;$ on the extreme left side in order to apply the squeeze theorem? Otherwise you get $\;y\;$ on the right and $\;x\;$ on the left....

Answer (score 1):

It is $\max\{x,y\}.$ The case when $x$ or $y$ is $-\infty$ needs the interpretation $t^{-\infty}=0$, $\log_t\!0=-\infty$, and $\max\{-\infty,x\}=x.$